# how should I do to match uppercase words also containing colon

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i need to change uppercase matches to bold but including colon

```
$str = "GOOD MORNING:";
preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]{2,}(\s[A-Z]{2,})?)\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
```

it returns:

```
<b>GOOD MORNING</b>:
```

it should return:

```
<b>GOOD MORNING:</b>
```

all my tries made my replace stop wroking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the colon in your character class. or just before the closing parenthesis of you capturing group (with a question mark if you want it optional).

```
$str = preg_replace('~[A-Z]{2,}(?:\s[A-Z]{2,})?:?~', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

Notice: word boundaries are not needed here, since the regex engine begin from the left and your quantifier `{2,}` is greedy)

Comment: i've tried but it didn't work it was returning my string blank

Comment: if i remove `{2,}` won't it replace uppercase letters?

Comment: @EddieD.: `{2,}` means two or more, if you want you can replace it by `+` whitch means one or more.

Comment: i see... well i just need to prevent it to replace single letters

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/([A-Z]{2,}\s[A-Z]{2,}:?)/", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
```

Output:

```
<b>GOOD MORNING:</b>
```

Comment: @EddieD. - I just modified and tested it. It worked fine and returned the result shown above.

Comment: @EddieD. - What to you mean? It returns the output I showed above in the `<b>` tags. I tested it, and that's what it returns.

Comment: it returned `GOOD MORNING:` to me

Comment: preg_replace can only return what it's given. If you have `"<b>$1</b>"` as the second parameter of the function, it will return the text within the `<b>` tags. How could it return anything else?

Comment: i gonna try once more

Comment: i did... it failed again

Comment: The output that I showed was copied and pasted from the actual output that I got, so I don't know what you're doing wrong. There's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: i don't know what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work for you,

```
$str = "GOOD MORNING";
preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]{2,}(\s[A-Z]{2,})?)\b/", "<b>$1:</b>", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways:

Any of the following should suffice:

1. `preg_replace("/([A-Z:]{2,}(\s[A-Z:]{2,})?)/", "<b>$1</b>", $str);`
2. `preg_replace("/([A-Z]{2,}(\s[A-Z:]{2,})?)/", "<b>$1</b>", $str);`
3. `preg_replace("/([A-Z]{2,}(\s[A-Z]{2,})?:?)/", "<b>$1</b>", $str);`

Here is my test output:

```
<?php
$str = "GOOD MORNING:";
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z:]{2,}(\s+[A-Z:]{2,})?)/', "<b>$1</b>", $str);
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2,}(\s+[A-Z:]{2,})?)/', "<b>$1</b>", $str);
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2,}(\s+[A-Z]{2,})?:?)/', "<b>$1</b>", $str);
?>
```

> Midget:~ masud$ php foo.php

```
<b>GOOD MORNING:</b><b>GOOD MORNING:</b><b>GOOD MORNING:</b>
```